# Image from AS3 to Javascript, then to Facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook, actionscript-3, api

There is a way to pass a BitArray, or Bitmap from an AS3 app

to Javascript (via ExternalInterface) and then publish this image/bitmap on

Facebook using the FB Javascript SDK or PHP SDK??

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You will need some server side processing in order to create the image to send to FB. What you should do is have your flash send a request to a php doc that saves the image, then use the FB php sdk to send the image over.

You cannot process and image in just js, you'll need to at the very least create a temp server side version.

Here's a bit of the php for the upload -

```
$file = $_POST['img']; // relative URL to image

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '1234234',
  'secret' => '12312412312',
));

$facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);
$args = array('message' => 'I just uploaded a pic!');
$args['image'] = '@' . $file;

$data = $facebook->api('/me/photos', 'post', $args);
```

I am passing the php my image location via javascript ajax and then it takes care of the rest - this is all assuming you have already asked for permission for your app!

Comment: Hi Drew thanks to reply. Hi have another question: I must to pass to the FB.api('me/photos') method A. The $GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"] received by PHP?, or B. the url of the image recently saved on the server ? MANY THANKS.

Comment: you can totally use the local version on the server. I've updated my answer with a bit of php for uploading :)

Answer (score 0):

The AS3 Facebook API supports the uploading of `BitmapData` as `ByteArray` for all of Facebook's API commands.

http://code.google.com/p/facebook-actionscript-api/